# iOS Multitasking and OpenGL ES resources

Tags: ios, opengl-es

After reading the documentation at [OpenGL ES Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3ddrawing/conceptual/opengles_programmingguide/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication/ImplementingaMultitasking-awareOpenGLESApplication.html), it is my understanding that my OpenGL ES resources will never be deleted without my application also being terminated. Is this true?

Comment: Is this question clear? I'm asking if it is true that "resources-deleted implies application-terminated".

Comment: The question is not clear but just to explain what this article is about: For instance, when an android application goes to background all GL content is released and has to be reloaded when coming back. iOS application will not delete anything unless you so specify or the application is terminated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true. iOS will not delete your application's resources and also allow your application to continue running (background or otherwise) - if you applications resources are deleted, your application will also be terminated.